# Remove blue box around buttons. HTML

Tags: html

I am currently making a site and adding the menu buttons. My problem is that when ever i click a button there is a blue box around it. I have try to at

```
 <button type="button" style="border:none; border-style:none"></button>
 <li style="border:none; border-style:none"></li>
 <a style="border:none; border-style:none" href="#">Home</a>
```

And they all don't work. My code is currently..

```
 <button type="button"><li><a href="music.html">Music</a></li></button>
```

I have tried all the border = none and tried 0 with both border-style and border-color. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Firefox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the below CSS style,

```
button
{
    outline: 0 none;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't outline: none; work just as well? That's what I've done for years.

Answer (score 3):

Css outline property may not work all the times .
here is a quick solution ;

```
* {
outline: none;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="file"] > input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner {
border: none;
}
```