# How to remove the blue highlight of button on mobile?

Tags: css, mobile

I try to remove the blue box that appears on click in front of buttons as you can see below:
[image: My button]

Before asking, I have made a lot of research, I have tried the solutions given by the following topics:

- [How to remove focus border (outline) around text/input boxes? (Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397113/how-to-remove-border-outline-around-text-input-boxes-chrome)
- [Remove blue box around buttons. HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22746464/remove-blue-box-around-buttons-html)
- [How to remove the blue box shadow border in button if clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222798/how-to-remove-the-blue-box-shadow-border-in-button-if-clicked)
- [How do I remove blue "selected" outline on buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20593224/remove-blue-selected-outline-on-buttons/43773106#43773106)
- [How do I remove blue "selected" outline on buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20593224/remove-blue-selected-outline-on-buttons)
- [Remove blue border from css custom-styled button in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340138/remove-blue-border-from-css-custom-styled-button-in-chrome)
- [How to remove focus around buttons on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053181/how-to-remove-focus-around-buttons-on-click)

I have tried all the answers! It works on computer but not on mobile.

If you are using a computer, you can try by simulating mobile with the inspector. Here is the button: https://jsfiddle.net/t4ykshst/

```css
#add {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    text-align: center;
    background: #1abc9c;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#add:active {
    opacity: 0.85;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="add" value="+" title="" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 52px; height: 52px;" />
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/t4ykshst/3/

Comment: Your example works fine for me.

Answer (score 365, accepted):

You can add:

```css
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
```

You can also add this to your stylesheets to define it globally:

```css
input,
textarea,
button,
select,
a {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

Refer to [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/AdjustingtheTextSize/AdjustingtheTextSize.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006510-SW5) for more information.

Comment: are there other vendor prefixes for other service providers? is this standardized yet?

Comment: don't forgot to add div :)

Comment: Finally! this is what I was looking for - thank you

Comment: I know I shouldn't comment like this, but this is awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Tailwind equivalent: `@layer base {
  html {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  }
}` https://css-tricks.com/custom-tailwind-css/

Answer (score 50):

This will apply the `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent` for all elements

```css
* {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

Test it.

Answer (score 9):

You just need to add
`style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;"`

Answer (score 6):

There will be no highlighting (at least in Chrome 88+) at all if you remove `cursor: pointer` from `#add` selector. And if you need it in the "desktop" mode, use something like this:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #add {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are many mobile screens larger than 768px, and it will not have any effect on those screens.

Answer (score 4):

`-webkit-tap-highlight-color` is a non-standard feature ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-tap-highlight-color)). It won't work in browser like safari 14.

Instead, you can use

```
{ outline: none; }
```

or apply it specifically through selector

```
a:focus,a:visited,a:active{
  outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try it

add to the button style "cursor: default;"

This will make a cursor:pointer; it turns into a "default", but will remove the blue shadow on the buttons on the mobile screen as you want

Comment: thanks. I was just about to answer the same. What a crazy thing the cursor causing back color to change. Almost 1 hour lost with this!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to all the answers here, you have to also specify the background css property explicitly yourself to the button.

Comment: The only answer that works 100%! I don't know why people down vote this answer, but this answer clearly works! You need to add "-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;" to the button property directly.

Comment: What browser(s) did you encounter this in?